# Cant render an outputText depending on my systemLocal Variable

Tags: oracle-adf, webcenter

I have a page template that in webcenter portal with footer with 2 output text which will be rendered depending on the selected language from the language task flow.

I have custom template which I've created with the jdeveloper 
and had put the follwing output label:

```
 <af:outputFormatted id ="copyright" rendered="#    {facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale} eq 'en'" value="the english text"   />


 <af:outputFormatted id ="copyright" rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale} eq 'ar'" value="the arabic text"   />
```

And this El expression always return false
so how to render this components depending on the selected language?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are closing your el expression too soon ("requestLocale **}**") . To fix it, replace :

```
<af:outputFormatted id="copyright" rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale} eq 'en'" value="the english text"   />
```

by

```
<af:outputFormatted id="copyright" rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale eq 'en'}" value="the english text"   />
```

Or, as an alternative solution, you can have only one outputFormatted with all values like this :

```
<af:outputFormatted id="copyright"  value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale eq 'en' ? 'the english text':(facesContext.externalContext.requestLocale eq 'ar' ? 'the arabic text' : 'Default text')}"   />
```

However if you are looking for a translation functionnality in ADF you should go for a translation bundle file as explain in the documentation here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31973/af_global.htm#ADFUI425

> Internationalization is the process of designing and developing products for easy adaptation to specific local languages and cultures. Localization is the process of adapting a product for a specific local language or culture by translating text and adding locale-specific components. A successfully localized application will appear to have been developed within the local culture. JDeveloper supports easy localization of ADF Faces components using the abstract class java.util.ResourceBundle to provide locale-specific resources.
>
> When your application will be viewed by users in more than one
>   country, you can configure your JSF page or application to use
>   different locales so that it displays the correct language for the
>   language setting of a user's browser. For example, if you know your
>   page will be viewed in Italy, you can localize your page so that when
>   a user's browser is set to use the Italian language, text strings in
>   the browser page will appear in Italian.
>
> ADF Faces components may include text that is part of the component,
>   for example the af:table component uses the resource string
>   af_table.LABEL_FETCHING for the message text that is displayed in the
>   browser while the table is fetching data during the initial load of
>   data or while the table is being scrolled. JDeveloper provides
>   automatic translation of these text resources into 28 languages. These
>   text resources are referenced in a resource bundle. If you set the
>   browser to use the language in Italy, any text contained within the
>   components will automatically be displayed in Italian. For more
>   information on skins and resource bundles, see Chapter 20,
>   "Customizing the Appearance Using Styles and Skins".
>
> For any text you add to a component, for example if you define the
>   label of an af:commandButton component by setting the text attribute,
>   you must provide a resource bundle that holds the actual text, create
>   a version of the resource bundle for each locale, and add a
>    element to define default and support locales in the
>   application's faces-config.xml file. You must also add a 
>    element to your application's faces-config.xml file
>   in order to make the resource bundles available to all the pages in
>   your application. Once you have configured and registered a resource
>   bundle, the Expression Language (EL) editor will display the key from
>   the bundle, making it easier to reference the bundle in application
>   pages.
>
> To simplify the process of creating text resources for text you add to
>   ADF components, JDeveloper supports automatic resource bundle
>   synchronization for any translatable string in the visual editor. When
>   you edit components directly in the visual editor or in the Property
>   Inspector, text resources are automatically created in the base
>   resource bundle.