# how to select resource bundle depend on selected locale in adf?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have .jspx template which has header, content and footer

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

    <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
              xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
              xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
              xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
              xmlns:rah="http://xmlns.oracle.com/webcenter/resourcehandler"
              xmlns:wcdc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/webcenter/spaces/taglib">
```

and I have 2 properties files ar.properties and en.properties.
in the footer I have a copyright message
that will be displayed depending on the selected locale

so I've done that

```
 <af:outputFormatted value=" جميع الحقوق محفوظة "  rendered="#{facesContext.ELContext.locale eq 'ar'}" />
 <af:outputFormatted value="all right reserved "  rendered="#{facesContext.ELContext.locale eq 'en'}" />
```

and it work fine but this way isn't effiecient because i will have to duplicate every labael in the whole page

I tried to put

```
<c:set var="bundle" value="{#facesContext.ELContext.locale eq 'en' ? {adfBundle['com.en']} : {adfBundle['com.ar']}}" />
```

and used only one output label

```
<af:outputFormatted value="#{bundle.copyright}"  />
```

but it gives me a warning that reference bundle is not found.
how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the, not yet validated, answer provided on your previous question, ([Cant render an outputText depending on my systemLocal Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326140/cant-render-an-outputtext-depending-on-my-systemlocal-variable/54328362#54328362))

You can follow this easy to read documentation on how to create a localization bundle : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31973/af_global.htm#ADFUI433

You are right to use your second approach with bundles to have a translatable value. If you have a "reference bundle is not found" warning it means that you missed the part where you have to define the bundle in your project properties.

See **21.2.1 How to Set Resource Bundle Options**:

> After you have created a project, you can set resource bundle options in the Project Properties dialog.
>
> To set resource bundle options for a project:
>
> In the Application Navigator, double-click the project.
>
> In the Project Properties dialog, select Resource Bundle to display
>   the resource bundle options, as shown in Figure 21-3.
>
> Figure 21-3 Project Properties Resource Bundle dialog
>
> Project Properties Resource Bundle. If you want JDeveloper to
>   automatically generate a default resource file, select Automatically
>   Synchronize Bundle.
>
> Select one of the following resource bundle file options:
>
> One Bundle Per Project - configured in a file named
>   .properties.
>
> One Bundle Per Page - configured in a file named
>   .properties.
>
> Multiple Shared Bundles.
>
> Select the resource bundle type from the dropdown list:
>
> XML Localization Interchange File Format (XLIFF) Bundle
>
> List Resource Bundle
>
> Properties Bundle
>
> Click OK.